# Problems filtering rows with Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE)

Tags: support, data-explorer, sql

I want to study how people behave where they are near to get a Tag Badge, so I need to:

1. Extract all the ID of users who have won a Tag Badge in a certain period of time.
2. See what Tag Badge they have won
3. Analyze for each user, and corresponding tag, the historic series of answers.

I have no idea about how to filter rows in order to satisfy point 3.
This is what I wrote:

```
select posts.owneruserid as 'User',
       posts.creationdate as 'Answer Date', 
       tags.tagname as 'Tag Name'
from posts
join posttags on posts.parentid=posttags.postid
join tags on posttags.tagid=tags.id
where posts.posttypeid=2 
      and 
      posts.owneruserid in ( select top 100 badges.userid
                             from badges
                             where badges.tagbased=1
                             and
                             badges.date > '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
                           )
 order by posts.owneruserid desc
```

With this, I query all the answers of (top 100) users, not just ones corresponding to the tag they won.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/550498) would work, using a temporary table:

```sql
create table #badges (userid int, name nvarchar(50) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS);
insert into #badges
select top 100 userid, name
  from badges
  where badges.tagbased = 1
    and badges.date > '2016-01-01 00:00:00';

select posts.owneruserid as 'User',
       posts.creationdate as 'Answer Date', 
       tags.tagname as 'Tag Name'
from posts
join posttags on posts.parentid = posttags.postid
join tags on posttags.tagid = tags.id
join #badges on #badges.userid = posts.owneruserid
 and #badges.name = tags.tagname
where posts.posttypeid = 2
 order by posts.owneruserid desc
```

Note the specified collation to avoid the problem mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276221/let-the-default-collation-of-the-sede-databases-match-the-dominant-collation-use).

I was afraid that not limiting the badges would cause the query to timeout, but [apparently it doesn't](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/550502), so this is probably what you want in the end.

```
select posts.owneruserid as 'User',
       posts.creationdate as 'Answer Date', 
       tags.tagname as 'Tag Name'
from posts
join posttags on posts.parentid = posttags.postid
join tags on posttags.tagid = tags.id
join badges on badges.userid = posts.owneruserid
 and badges.name = tags.tagname
where posts.posttypeid = 2
  and badges.tagbased = 1
  and badges.date > '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
 order by posts.owneruserid desc
```

Happy querying!

Comment: Thank you @glorfindel for your help! It does exactly what I want. That third "join" solved all my problems.