# Why can I not filter the Posts table in data.stackexchange by tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, search, data-explorer

While trying to write a query on https://data.stackexchange.com/datascience/, using the Posts table, I cannot filter by tags.
For instance, if I try to extract the tags from the Posts table:

```
select tags
from Posts
```

I get a table with a row containing 'machine-learning'.

However, if I then filter the table using that tag, the resulting table is empty.

```
select *
from Posts
where tags = 'machine-learning'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I write SQL queries on an unfamiliar database, I tend to check how filters work on records I expect to satisfy (part of) the query. That should make one notice *how* the `Posts.Tags` results look like - it contains *all* tags of the question, separated by angle brackets, e.g. `<machine-learning><another-tag>`.

However, in this particular case, the angle brackets are difficult to notice, because `TagName` is a [magic column](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#magic-columns) with special formatting - you should try using the option 'Text-only results' to see the difference.

The query you're looking for is

```
select *
from Posts
where tags like '%<machine-learning>%'
```

or, if that is not performant enough, join with `PostTags` and `Tags` and filter on `Tags.TagName`. For more information, please have a look at the [schema documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/295232).

Comment: One might be able to get some additional speed up by collating the tags column as `Latin1_General_BIN`. fact-check needed. I am a SQL newbie.

Comment: @starball I'll defer to rene for that. I'm happy to know how to account for collation, how that affects performance is out of my league ...

Comment: @starball I don't think it will work on some language sites, like [Japanese.SE](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags)?

Comment: @starball if performance is an issue, the joining with posttags is probable the way to go. If you still feel you need a collation, pick one that the row is already in so SQL doesn't have to do a re-encoding for every row in the result. There is still something to desire for SEDE default collation: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276221/let-the-default-collation-of-the-sede-databases-match-the-dominant-collation-use